# Dojo require - error on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, struts2, dojo

I'm using Dojo to issue SMD calls in a Struts2 framework.

When including this line `dojo.require("dojo.rpc.JsonService");` i'm getting an error on Firefox's console:

```
not well-formed (JsonService.js)
not well-formed (RpcService.js)
not well-formed (url.js)
```

I researched a bit about this but there's no clear answer yet. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you open Firefox's dev tools and you inspect the network responses for these files, what does the content-type header say?  I ask because I have seen cases in the past where some web application servers report JS files with an XML content type for some absurd reason, which generated spurious warnings in Firefox.

Comment: How do you use dojo? The files are you looking might not be available in the version of dojo which you are using.

Comment: @KenFranqueiro You are right! I modified my web.xml to properly define the mime mapping for JS files and the error is no longer thrown.

Comment: @KenFranqueiro: You should convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: Cool, nice to hear that worked, it was a wild guess which is why I commented first :) I added an answer now as Aleksandr suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some web application servers don't report proper Content-Type headers for JavaScript files, defaulting to reporting them as XML instead.  In these cases, Firefox will report spurious messages like this.

Check the Content-Type headers reported for JS files in the Network tab of your developer tools, and update your server's configuration if necessary.